# Net_device structure getting corrupted on linux 2.4.29 kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am facing a strange issue. In a running system I can see that ethernet interface is getting deleted. It can be confirmed from `ifconfig -a` command. On firing this command ethernet interface can't be seen but a corrupted entry for netrom interface starts appearing which was not visible when system was running fine. The corrupted entry which is seen is as below (output of `ifconfig` command):

```
Link encap:AMPR NET/ROM  HWaddr 
              [NO FLAGS]  MTU:0  Metric:1 
              RX packets:17648365 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
              TX packets:17224514 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:814973822 (777.2 Mb)  TX bytes:960071444 (915.5 Mb)
```

To me it seems net_device structure has got corrupted. As we are having old linux kernel (2.4.29) so not able to find ways to debug corrupted memory. Please help.

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow doesn't provide a support for 3d party code.

Comment: What has changed between when it was ok and now ?

Comment: Is there any reason you're using a kernel that is *seventeen* years old?